# Problema con imagen en reporte GX X EVO3 con C# y SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, sql-server, genexus

ESTIMADOS: Ojalá pueden darme una mano con este problemita.

Tengo un webPanel desde donde llamo a un reporte.

En este webPanel se genera un valor en una variable de texto en formato data uri PNG. **Por ejemplo:**

> &txt1 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQ....."

En el webPanel, tengo un control Image y para ver la imagen, solo escribo:

> miImagen.Bitmap = &txt1 // funciona correctamente.

El problema es que paso como parametro el `&txt1` a un procedure reporte en el que se debe imprimir esa imagen, **PERO NO SE COMO ASIGNAR** el valor de `&txt1` a una variable tipo img o a un control Image (o que control u otro tipo de variable se necesita).

He probado varias formas mediante los métodos de la variable tipo Image pero no consigo que se vea en el reporte. Tambien consulté en la web y al parecer se debería usar una variable tipo Blob, pero tampoco funciona.

Trabajo con GX X EVO3 - C# y SQL SERVER

Gracias por tu tiempo!
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los Reportes necesitan la ruta de la Imagen. En tu caso le estás pasando el base64.

Lo que puedes hacer es un Proceso previo que salve los Base64 a archivos y luego en vez de referenciar el base64 desde el Reporte, incluir las rutas a las Imágenes correspondientes.

El proceso para pasar de Base64 a File es algo así:

```
    &File.Source = "image.png" 
    &File.Create()
    &File.FromBase64String('R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM//....') 
    &File.Close()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Gonzalo, voy a probar y comento como fue...

Answer (score 0):

Hola: Pude resolver el problema de esta manera:
Desde el webPanel llamo al procedure reporte así:

```
printQR( &imgTexto) // esta variable contiene un png en formato data base64
```

**Luego en el Source del procedure report:**

```
&imgTexto= substr(&imgParametro,23,1000)
&imgBlob.FromBase64String( &imgTexto)
&imgPrint = &imgBlob 

Donde:
&imgParametro C(1000) paramétro que recibe el procedure
&imgText C(1000) es un substring de imgParametro desde char 23.
&imgBlob tipo Blob 
FromBase64String( &imgTexto) convierte &imgTexto para almacenar en Blob
&imgPrint tipo Image
```

imgTexto contiene en sus primeros caracteres, la cadena "data:image/png;base64," que no forma parte de la data de la imagen, por lo que con susbstr tomo desde el caracter 23 hasta el final y se guarda en &imgText que a su vez luego se pasa a &imgBlob. Por ultimo este Blob se asigna a &imgPrint del Layout.

```
GRACIAS A LOS QUE SE INTERESARON POR ESTE TEMA. 
Saludos
```

Comment: Genail! Si, de esa manera es más sencilla.