# No puedo visualizar un Código QR en un reporte PDF con GX X EVO3

Tags: c#, genexus

Necesito encontrar la solución para imprimir un código QR en un reporte PDF.
En un procedure report tengo en el source lo siguiente:

```
&txtBase64 = &webQrCode.Get('ws_txtQRBase64')
&txtBase64= substr(&txtBase64,23,5000)
&qrBlob.FromBase64String( &txtBase64 )
&qrPrint = &qrBlob 
//qrPrint es de tipo Image y qrBlob de tipo blob.
```

**En un pequeño proyecto (Windows 10) no hay problemas para ver el código QR en el reporte**. Pero al importarlo desde otro, que es donde debe funcionar (Windows XP 32bits), no muestra la imagen en el reporte. Se probó con Chrome y FireFox. El problema será la versión de Windows? En ambos equipos se usa el .NET 3.5

> Podrán orientarme para solucionarlo? Muchas gracias!!! Uso GX X Evo3 U11. C#

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Problema con imagen en reporte GX X EVO3 con C# y SQL SERVER](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/240135/problema-con-imagen-en-reporte-gx-x-evo3-con-c-y-sql-server)

Comment: NO ES DUPLICADO. Esta consulta no tiene solución en **Problema con imagen en reporte GX X EVO3 con C# y SQL SERVER**., como me sugieres. En esa pregunta no podía ver el código QR. En esta pregunto indico que el código QR SI se puede visualizar, pero al exportar la rutina e importarla en otra KB, el código no aparece. Digo: "En un pequeño proyecto (Windows 10) **no hay problemas para ver el código QR en el reporte**" Muchas gracias por tu comentario.